# How to handle websocket validation in marshmallow?

Tags: python, marshmallow

Getting validation error on the `ws_url` field

`{'ws_url': ['Not a valid URL.']}`

Here is the schema:

```py
class ExplicitUri(Schema):
    rpc_url = fields.Url(required=True)
    ws_url = fields.Url(required=False)
```

when data is either `ws://x.y.z:90` or `wss://x.y.z:90`.

Do I need to create a custom validator?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think marshmallow is dynamic enough at its core to allow for clean and succinct serialisation. I would write one which detects field type with regex or possibly parses then type checks. Its simpler and you don't have to write model classes. But you should boot your regex skills they are fundamental.